# How to improve the quality of a video made with Xuggler

Tags: java, video, xuggler

I'm using the a bunch of png files to create a video.My problem is that while the png files are of an OK quality the video frames won't render in a good enough quality.Do you know how i can fix such a thing? Here is the code i've written concerning the matter:

```
    private void createVideo() throws IOException{


    IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename);
    Dimension screenBounds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,screenBounds.width/2, screenBounds.height/2);

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    File directory = new File(sourceFolder);
    ArrayList<File> filenames = new ArrayList<File> ();

    File[] list= directory.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        filenames.add(list[i]);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < filenames.size(); index++) {
        if(filenames.get(index).toString().contains("png")){

            BufferedImage screen = ImageIO.read(filenames.get(index));

            // convert to the right image type
            BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen,BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);


            int i=0;
            while(i<FRAME_RATE){
                writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, 
                   TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                ++i;
            }

            // sleep for frame rate milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    writer.close();     

}
```

**Solution:** the problem was this line

```
writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,screenBounds.width/2, screenBounds.height/2);
```

I shouldn't have divided the width and height with 2 after i removed it the quality was   just as the png it self.

Comment: What do you mean by `in good quality`

Comment: Well,these png files contain graphs.When the video is created the label near each vertex won't appear clearly.Generally each frame appears really blurry.On the contrary each png used to create this video seems ok

Comment: Size issue. Image smaller than the video size. Try a set of very large images. Maybe something clicked from a DSLR camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by `in a good quality` but assuming that you mean it looks blurred out, it could be that

**PNG image is smaller in size compared to the size in which you want it encoded.**

This will mean less pixels to encode into the video stream. This will result in pixels being spread out and hence looking of poor quality.

Comment: You need bigger images. Higher resolution :)

Comment: hehe i didn't forget i was just checking.By the way i don't think this was it..I've fixed it and i'll post the correct code just in case...

Comment: i've just posted it! :) i did accept your answer since it helped me figure it out